# How to localize the text that comes from control attribute of Video tag in HTML5

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using a video tag in my .cshtml file of the MVC application

```
<video src = "imageSource controls" />
```

When we write "**controls**" attribute inside the video tag, it gives options like play, pause, and so on. When we click on Elipsis(3 dotted button) it was displaying 2 options "**Download**" and "**Picture in picture**".

My requirement is to Localize those two words. How can I gain control over it?

Attaching link for reference
[TextToBeLocalize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3caI.png)

Comment: That control is localised by the browser. The language shown will be determined by the locale the user has selected in their settings. There is nothing you can do to amend that in the standard video control. If you need to change it you will need to use a third-party video player which builds the controls using HTML which can be changed.

Comment: I agree with Rory, if he wrote his comment as an answer I'd suggest it should be marked as the accepted one.